# Excel get cells value if cells contain specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I have Table 1 & 2 like image.
How i can get all cells value if ID is equals?

Comment: I would look for something like "group by" or "group". that's how databases solve it and sometimes excel is similar in that regard.

Comment: Is your values are numbers ? You can use SumIF function.

Comment: Thanks @kronn and @Elnur Ibrahim, but i was used `phpexcel` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to add numbers, there are formulas for this, but I'm not sure if there's a single formula for adding string values as in the provided example.  One way to resolve this is by using accumulator columns as in this screen shot:

[image]

The formula in cell C3 is:

```
=IF($A3<>C$1,C2,IF(C2=0,$B3,C2&", "&$B3))
```

Copy this down to cell E10 (or wherever that table needs to end) and columns C to E will accumulate the values from column B.  Table 2 then just maps the first and last rows of the accumulator columns.  The zeros in cells C2 to E2 is a work-around to prevent Excel from converting blank cells into zeros.

Hope this helps!